Xcode 15 is not running in macOS sequoia
I’ve updated macOS to latest sequoia. I’ve Xcode 15 before updated macOS sequoia. After updation macOS to latest. Xcode stopped running

me too.  i dont especially care which version of xcode, just want it to stop giving me that error and let git work again : (

Run XCode 15 in Mac OS Sequoia:
Xcode 15 versions are not supported on Mac OS Sequoia but here is a workaround to get it to run the Xcode 15 version in MacOS Sequoia.
Any Xcode 15 version App —> Right click —> Show package contents —> Contents —> MacOS —> Xcode (Double click),  Thats it then it will open Xcode 15

Is it right way to open XCode 15 in unsupported macOS will it create any issue in build/archive in react native project ?

this saved me.  although running tests has been throwing a "cannot launch simulator" error / alert from within this version of Xcode.

I hope this has no ill effects.. I am fine developing on XCode16, but I want to run my app on my ios12 iPad mini!!

I've just replaced Info.plist file of Xcode 15.4 with Info.plist from Xcode 16.0 - and it worked like a charm!
Xcode 15.4 properly launches, handles project and associated file opens, etc.
Update
Even more!

Backup Xcode 15 plist to some location
Replace Info.plist of Xcode 15 with Info.plist from Xcode 16
Launch Xcode 15 (should be launched now)
Quit Xcode 15
Put back original Info.plist to Xcode 15
And everything works!


I can't get past agreeing to the terms with this method.

Strange. When I've found this approach, first I've launched and installed Xcode 16. When I found that it is not convenient for me, I've reverted back to Xcode 15. Maybe you should pass Xcode 16 agreement first

Same for me, i press agree, touchId, and nothing happens, the agreement window just stays here. Already have a working xcode16 with passed agreement on the mac

I got past the terms by switching back to the Xcode 15 Info.plist.

A bit simpler is to edit the Info.plist file and set CFBundleVersion to 23051 (the bundle version of Xcode 16.0

@txulu this breaks the signature

% sudo cp /tmp/Info.plist .
cp: ./Info.plist: Operation not permitted

cat /tmp/Info.plist > Info.plist worked but it's stuck on the license agreement prompt. Pressing agree does nothing.Disagree of course quits the app.

This only seems to work with 16.0. I could not get it to work when using Xcode 16.1.

Another simple way is to change the Info.plist's CFBundleVersion to 23051 (the one from Xcode 16.0).
You might need to modify the exact path to your Xcode:
defaults write /Applications/Xcode-15.4.0.app/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleVersion -string 23051


2024-11-15 13:46:55.607 defaults[93157:10692354] Could not write domain /Applications/Xcode-15.4.app/Contents/Info.plist; exiting

@AntonTropashko you can do it from Finder: right-click on the XCode 15 app, "Show Package Content", navigate to the plist and edit "by hand". Worked to me.

Terminal command didn't work for me. By hand, I copied the original plist, replaced the version to 23051, and put it back. Build and run on the simulator now works.

In addition to the approved answer, after opening the XCode 15 you can go to settings and Locations, then change the command line tools to XCode 15 so that you can build your cross-platform apps such as Flutter without a problem again
I had a problem with my Flutter environment after the mac os update. I installed xcode 15.4 from here and followed the simple steps in the approved answer. And changed the command line tool settings from the xcode settings and I made it work.


It works! However, my Flutter apps still won't build from Android Studio on iOS devices. It seems the android studio still uses the XCode 16's command line tools. Is there any workaround for building the app directly from the Android Studio?

To extend already given answers:

For Android studio and system in general use Xcode 15.4 you should select correct Xcode for the system by typing in terminal sudo xcode-select -s <path/to/>Xcode.app
If you same as me could not pass agreement dialog you can pass it calling Xcode build licence in terminal sudo xcodebuild -license


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

1: Go to application folder on your Mac.
2: You will find Xcode app, Right Click on it.
3: Select "Show Package Content", it will redirect to "Contents" folder.
4: You will find "MacOS" folder inside "Contents" folder.
5: Open "MacOS" folder you will find "Xcode" option inside it.
7: Double click Xcode option and it will open it automatically in terminal and will run some command. Let it complete.
8: Now open Xcode it will work.

great trick!  Worked for me!  Some things don't work, like running tests with a simulator that needs a UI, but now with a mostly modular codebase, this doesn't hurt us that badly.

You can use this script to make a shortcut for the Shortcuts app:
#!/bin/bash
# Define the path to Xcode
XCODE_PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app"
# Define the path to the Xcode executable file
XCODE_EXECUTABLE="$XCODE_PATH/Contents/MacOS/Xcode"
# Launch Xcode
if [ -e "$XCODE_EXECUTABLE" ]; then
    echo "Launching Xcode..."
    "$XCODE_EXECUTABLE"
else
    echo "Xcode not found."
fi

